# Adding Radial Axis Label in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a polar scatter plot for a college project with matplotlib and I can't find out how to add a label to the radial axis. Here is my code ( I left out the data because it was read out of a csv)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_rmax(1)
c = plt.scatter(theta, radii)
ax.set_title("Spread of Abell Cluster Supernova Events as a Function of Fractional Radius", va='bottom')
ax.legend(['Supernova'])
plt.show()
```

(My plot looks like [this](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/polar_scatter.html). I can't seem to find any straight forward method to do it. Has anyone dealt with this before and have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a built in way to do it, but you could use `ax.text` to make your own. You can get the position of the radial tick labels using `ax.get_rlabel_position()`, and the mid point of the radial axis using `ax.get_rmax()/2.`

For example, here's your code (with some random data):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta=np.random.rand(40)*np.pi*2.
radii=np.random.rand(40)

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_rmax(1)
c = plt.scatter(theta, radii)
ax.set_title("Spread of Abell Cluster Supernova Events as a Function of Fractional Radius", va='bottom')
ax.legend(['Supernova'])

label_position=ax.get_rlabel_position()
ax.text(np.radians(label_position+10),ax.get_rmax()/2.,'My label',
        rotation=label_position,ha='center',va='center')

plt.show()
```

And here's the output:

[image]

I'd be interested to see if there's a more elegant solution, but hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

```
from pylab import *

N = 150
r = 2*rand(N)
theta = 2*pi*rand(N)
area = 200*r**2*rand(N)
colors = theta
ax = subplot(111, polar=True)
c = scatter(theta, r, c=colors, s=area, cmap=cm.hsv)
c.set_alpha(0.75)
ax.set_ylabel('Radius', rotation=45, size=11)

show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different method from @tom. This uses directly the `plt.legend` option.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta=np.random.rand(40)*np.pi*2.
radii=np.random.rand(40)

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_rmax(1)
c = plt.scatter(theta, radii,label='Supernova')
ax.set_title("Spread of Abell Cluster Supernova Events as a Function of Fractional Radius", va='bottom')
ax.legend(loc='lower right', scatterpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

You can change `lower right` to `upper right` or even to `best` to leave the alignment of the legend to matplotlib.

[image]