# plotly polar plot: axis and background color

Tags: python, plotly

I have discovered plotly and have a few questions: I would like to change all axis to black (not white). Below modified example code from their webpage, where I have set both radial and angular axis to black. I can use linecolor = 'black', but it seems that then the line going to 0 is thicker than the others?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/hobbs-pearson-trials.csv")

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolargl(
      r = df.trial_1_r,
      theta = df.trial_1_theta,
      name = "Trial 1",
      marker=dict(size=10, color="mediumseagreen")
    ))

# Common parameters for all traces
fig.update_traces(mode="markers", marker=dict(line_color='black', opacity=0.7))

fig.update_layout(
    title = "",
    font_size = 15,
    showlegend = False,
    polar = dict(
      bgcolor = "rgb(223, 223, 223)",
      #bgcolor = "white",
      angularaxis = dict(
        linewidth = 3,
        showline=True,
        linecolor='black',
        gridcolor = "black"
      ),
      radialaxis = dict(
        side = "counterclockwise",
        showline = True,
        linewidth = 2,
        gridcolor = "black",
        gridwidth = 2,
      )
    ),
    paper_bgcolor = "white"
)

fig.show()

fig.write_image("plotlyPolar.svg", scale=2)
fig.write_image("plotlyPolar.jpg", scale=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```
I have made two changes
```

1. The code the you commented  `polar = dict[bgcolor = "white",]`
2. `paper_bgcolor = "#ffffff"`
3. `show_line = False`[image: newplot]

I have copied your and used `Jupyter` on anaconda python version (3.7/3.8)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/hobbs-pearson-trials.csv")
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolargl(
  r = df.trial_1_r,
  theta = df.trial_1_theta,
  name = "Trial 1",
  marker=dict(size=10, color="mediumseagreen")
))
# Common parameters for all traces
fig.update_traces(mode="markers", marker=dict(line_color='black', opacity=0.8))

fig.update_layout(
title = "",
font_size = 15,
showlegend = False,
polar = dict(
  #bgcolor = "rgb(223, 223, 223)",
  bgcolor = "white",
  angularaxis = dict(
    linewidth = 3,
    showline=True,
    linecolor='black',
    gridcolor = "black"
  ),
  radialaxis = dict(
    side = "counterclockwise",
    showline = False,
    linewidth = 3,
    gridcolor = "black",
    gridwidth = 2,
  )
),
paper_bgcolor = "#ffffff"
)

fig.show()

fig.write_image("plotlyPolar.svg", scale=2)
fig.write_image("plotlyPolar.jpg", scale=3)
```

Comment: thank you, that was very helpful! is there a way to have the text on the radialaxis to the front of the dots? I know that it is possible to make the dots more or less transparent but that does not seem to be sufficient

Comment: I haven't checked that myself but I hope this link might help you. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767000/bring-radial-axes-labels-in-front-of-lines-of-polar-plot-matplotlib)

Comment: or you can try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001494/adding-radial-axis-label-in-matplotlib). 
I hope this helps. Thankyou.